# Can only see first of two canvases (drawing using ionic framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, ionic-framework

I have a problem displaying two canvases on top of each other.

I'm using the ionic framework and easeljs to draw on one canvas. Now I want to also be able to see a cursor of varying size and color when using a mouse (not in-app of course), so I though I could draw on the lower layer canvas and show the cursor on a higher layer canvas, clearing it repeatedly on mouse move.

I have an ionic on-drag event, an on-touch event (both to draw) and an angujarjs ng-mousemove (for the cursor). I have to put all those events in the first canvas in the html file or they won't register.

The problem is that I can only see the content of that first layer. I though canvases were transparent objects so I could layer them on top of each other using a different z-index for each one.

The following is my code using ionic and easeljs, I tried to keep it as short as possible. If you run it this way you can only draw, but you don't see a cursor. If you switch out the ids layer0 and layer1 it is the other way around.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Doodle</title>

        <script src="ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="easeljs-0.8.1.combined.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

            .controller('DrawCtrl', function($scope) {

                var canvas, stage;
                var drawingCanvas;
                var oldPt;
                var oldMidPt;   

                canvas = document.getElementById("layer0");     
                //check to see if we are running in a browser with touch support
                stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
                stage.autoClear = false;
                stage.enableDOMEvents(true);    
                createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
                createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);         
                drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
                stage.addChild(drawingCanvas);          

                $scope.downEvent = function() {                 
                    oldPt = new createjs.Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
                    oldMidPt = oldPt.clone();
                };

                $scope.dragEvent = function() {
                    //draw on layer0, don't clear
                    oldPt.x = stage.mouseX;
                    oldPt.y = stage.mouseY;
                    var midPt = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX >> 1, oldPt.y + stage.mouseY >> 1);           
                    drawingCanvas.graphics.clear().setStrokeStyle(10, 'round', 'round').beginStroke("#000000").moveTo(midPt.x, midPt.y).curveTo(oldPt.x, oldPt.y, oldMidPt.x, oldMidPt.y);                  

                    oldMidPt.x = midPt.x;
                    oldMidPt.y = midPt.y;

                    stage.update();                 
                };

                $scope.mouseMove = function() { 
                    //draw circle on canvas during mouse move, immediately clear layer1 again (like a cursor)
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('layer1').getContext('2d');
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    var x = stage.mouseX;
                    var y = stage.mouseY;
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();                 
                };
            })
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="DrawCtrl">
        <canvas id="layer0" style="z-index:0; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180" ng-mousemove="mouseMove()" on-touch="downEvent($event)" on-drag="dragEvent()" <="" canvas="">
        <canvas id="layer1" style="z-index:1; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180" <="" canvas="">
    </canvas></canvas></body>
</html>
```

I'm just starting to learn html/javascript and would really appreciate any input!

Comment: `<="" canvas="">` What is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick guess, but your problem is probably in your canvas HTML lines:

```
<canvas id="layer0" style="z-index:0; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180" ng-mousemove="mouseMove()" on-touch="downEvent($event)" on-drag="dragEvent()" <="" canvas="">
<canvas id="layer1" style="z-index:1; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180" <="" canvas="">
```

This bit at the end: `<="" canvas="">` isn't quite valid. Replace those lines with:

```
<canvas id="layer0" style="z-index:0; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180" ng-mousemove="mouseMove()" on-touch="downEvent($event)" on-drag="dragEvent()"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer1" style="z-index:1; border: 1px solid black; " width="300" height="180"></canvas>
```

And remove the 2 trailing `</canvas></canvas>`.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I spend this long on a copy/paste error... Thank you! Now the two canvases are next to each other, but that is probably just a positioning issue.

Comment: a bit meta, but do I just delete a question like this? It's not like it is likely to help anyone else.

Comment: @freda42: Yea, that positioning something that can just be fixed with CSS. I don't really see the need to delete it. Someone may come here with a canvas issue, only to realize their HTML is incorrect as well.